# How to limit foreign keys in Rails association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails app I have `users` who can have many `projects` which in turn can have many `tasks`.

**model:**

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :project_id

end
```

**controller:**

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @task = current_user.tasks.build(params[:task])    
    if @task.save
      flash[:success] = "Task saved."
      redirect_to edit_task_path(@task)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    if @task.update_attributes(params[:task])
      flash[:success] = "Task updated."
      redirect_to edit_task_path(@task)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

end
```

What's the standard practice in Rails to ensure that a user **A** can not create a task for a user **B**?

Right now, I am restricting the `project_ids` that are available to a user through the select box options in the form. However, this can be easily hacked through a browser console and is not safe at all.

How can this be improved?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a before filter that checks if required project belongs to current user :

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_project, only: :create

  def create
    @task = @project.tasks.build(params[:task])    
    if @task.save
      flash[:success] = "Task saved."
      redirect_to edit_task_path(@task)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def find_project
    @project = current_user.projects.where( id: params[ :task ][ :project_id ] ).first
    redirect_to( root_path, notice: 'No such project' ) unless @project
  end
end
```

So, if given project_id does not match a project belonging to current user, he is redirected out.

A more rails way, though, would be to use nested resources :

```
resources :projects
  resources :tasks, shallow: true
end
```

You would have routes like this :

```
GET /projects/1/tasks (index)
GET /projects/1/tasks/new (new)
POST /projects/1/tasks (create)
GET /tasks/1 (show)
GET /tasks/1/edit (edit)
PUT /tasks/1 (update)
DELETE /tasks/1 (destroy)
```

But this won't differ much, you still have to retrieve Post :

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_project, only: [ :index, :new, :create ]
  before_filter :find_task, only: [ :show, :edit, :update, :delete ]

  # other actions

  def create
    @task = @project.tasks.build(params[:task])    
    if @task.save
      flash[:success] = "Task saved."
      redirect_to edit_task_path(@task)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def find_project
    @project = current_user.projects.where( id: params[ :project_id ] ).first
    redirect_to( root_path, notice: 'No such project' ) unless @project
  end

  def find_task
    @task = current_user.tasks.where( id: params[ :id ] ).first
    redirect_to( root_path, notice: 'No such task' ) unless @task
  end
end
```

Comment: Hello Olivier, that works great, just tested it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use nested resources in my app. So I will have to stick with the first solution you provided. Since I am new to Rails: Could you show me how to adjust my `update` action as well? I am not sure how to get the `@project` variable in there. I assume running the filter on the `create` and `update` actions only will suffice from a security point of view?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is scope your lookup and exploit the fact that `#find` can raise `RecordNotFound`. Rails will rescue that exception and render 404 for you.

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :project

  def create
    @task = project.tasks.build(params[:task])    
    if @task.save
      flash[:success] = "Task saved."
      redirect_to edit_task_path(@task)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def project
    @project ||= current_user.projects.find(params[:task][:project_id])
  end
end
```

I would also add that you should also scope the URL for tasks under the project it belongs to. Something like `/projects/:project_id/tasks/:id` using nested resources.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution is pretty similar to what Olivier is suggesting. So I guess this is the way to go. I only wonder if I should adjust my `update` action as well and what that would have to look like? Unfortunately, I can't use nested resources in my app, though.